# Authenticating SSHD against AWS Simple Directory Service

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ssh, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-service

I am trying to setup a network of Centos 7 machines with sshd that authenticate public keys against an AWS Simple Directory Service directory.

Currently, I have a bunch of Centos hosts, an instance of Windows Server 2008, and a directory using Amazon Web Service (AWS) Simple Directory Service. The windows box is used to administer the directory, and the Centos boxes use the directory to authenticate SSH sessions. All machines have been joined to the directory.

I have verified that I am able to SSH into the Centos boxes as both local and domain users using simple password authentication. Similarly, I am able to RDP into the Windows box using both local and domain accounts, simple password authentication.

However, the schema setup by AWS in my directory did not include any classes with a `sshPublicKey` field out of the box, so to speak.

So, I used the Active Directory Schema Snap-in on the Windows box to add the following attribute to my schema:

```
Common Name: sshPublicKey
OOID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.1.1.1.13
Syntax: IA5-String
Multi-valued: true
```

I then created the following class:

```
Common Name: LDAP Public Key
OOID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 
Parent Class: top
Class Type: Auxiliary
Optional Attributes: sshPublicKey
```

Then, I used the ADSI Snap-in to add the content of a user's public key to the `sshPublicKey` field of their entry in the directory.

On one of my Centos boxes, I disabled password authentication by setting `PasswordAuthentication no` in sshd's config file.

Then, I attempted to ssh into that Centos box using the directory user with the `sshPublicKey` attribute set:

```
$ ssh -l user@directory.server -i ~/.ssh/path.to.key.pub centos.box -vvv;
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/localuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to centos.box [ip addy] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "~/.ssh/path.to.key.pub" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/path.to.key.pub type 1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/path.to.key.pub type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "centos.box" from file "/Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:someLineNumber
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 116/256
debug2: bits set: 535/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA blah
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "centos.box" from file "/Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:someLine
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'centos.box' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:27
debug2: bits set: 509/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/path.to.key.pub (0x7fb3cb600000), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/path.to.key.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
$
```

And on the Centos box, we get:

```
$ sudo journalctl -felu sshd
....
Some Date centos.box sshd[a number]: Connection closed by 1.2.3.4 [preauth]
```

Permissions on the private key are `600`; permissions on the public key are `644`

I'm not sure how to check the server logs on the directory service host.

Any ideas what I' doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure `sshd` talks to `sssd` for public key authentication, do the following on the `sshd` host:

1. Add the following line to the `[sssd]` section of your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file:

   ```
   services = ssh, [ all the other services already listed there as well ]
   ```

This tells `sssd` it should talk to `sshd`.

2. If there isn't already an `[ssh]` section there, add a blank `[ssh]` section of your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file:

   ```
   [ssh]
   ```

This is a required config section for all services to which `sssd` talks.

3. Add the following line to the `[domain/directory.server]` section of your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file, where `directory.server` is the fully qualified domain name of your directory service host:

   ```
   ldap_user_ssh_public_key = sshPublicKey
   ```

This tells `sssd` which attribute to use for finding `sshd` users' public SSH keys. ( [The default attribute used by `sssd` is `ipaSshPubKey`, which can be found on the schema for the `ipaSshUser` and `ipaSshHost` classes.](https://www.freeipa.org/images/1/10/Freeipa30_SSSD_OpenSSH_integration.pdf) )

4. Add the following lines into your `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` file:

   ```
   AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
   AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
   ```

This tells `sshd` to execute the file `/usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys` as user `nobody`.  `/usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys` fetches authorized keys for the user attempting to authenticate into the `sshd` host.

5. Add the following lines into your `/etc/sshd/ssh_config` file:

   ```
   GlobalKnownHostsFile /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts
   ProxyCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p %p %h
   ```

This tells `sssd` adds the client's name and public keys to `/var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts` and to connect to the client, pipes all communication through standard I/O, using the executable file `/usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy`.

6. Restart both services:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl reload sshd;
   $ sudo systemctl restart sshd;
   $ sudo systemctl restart sssd;
   ```

Comment: Thank you, great solution. For anyone else make sure to add sshPublicKey as an attribute to the User object in Active Directory Schema Snap-in.